# Dynamically Generating Sitemaps for Each Domain with Next.js 13.5 and i18next

Tags: next.js, internationalization, sitemap, i18next

I've looked into the Next.js documentation for generating static and dynamic sitemaps, but the examples provided do not cover scenarios with multiple domains and internationalization.
Has anyone successfully implemented a solution for dynamically generating sitemaps that accommodate multiple domains and automatically include new pages?